# Taking input of char* in array of struct

Tags: c++

```
struct student
{
       char *name;
       int roll_no;

};

student s1[3];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
        cout<<"Enter name: ";
        cin.getline(s1[i].name,'\n');
        cout<<"\nEnter roll number : ";
        cin>>s1[i].roll_no;        

}
```

I want to take full name input in "char* name", but this is not working
I know , I can use string but is there any way to do this with char* ?

Answer (score 2):

In struct student you define pointer to char, but does not allocate memory for it. You need something like

```
#define STRSIZE 255
struct student
{
       char name[STRSIZE];
       int roll_no;

};
...
cin.getline(s1[i].name, STRSIZE);
...
```

And second arg to getline is length of input buffer, not delimiter.

Comment: Correct, but please god no this is terrible. Use `std::string`. The _only_ reason to do this is to practice how not to do it. And, perhaps, if you're writing a library for C ... but the question is tagged [tag:c++]!

Comment: @Lightning Racis in Obrit I now how work with `std::string`. Just show the error in the authors code.

Comment: Yes, I understood that

Comment: @CodeLearner What exactly not working? Please, provide more information